# Haskell Encryption Program

Tags: haskell, encryption, xor

I am trying to write a program called encrypt that transforms a text file by scrambling each of its characters. This is achieved by providing a key (string) as a command line argument which is used to encode the input. Thus:

`cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ` will encrypt the text by matching up the text with the key infinitely.

```
The..
XXA..
The World...
XXAYSAAZZ etc..
The World is Not Enough etc...
XXAYSAAZZXXAYSAAZZXXAYS etc...
```

And `"exclusively-or-ing"` the corresponding characters. But due to the nature of **XOR** I am supposed to be able to retain the original text by doing this:

```
cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ | ./scramble XXAYSAAZZ
```

So far I have got this:

```
module Main where
import System
import Data.Char

main = do arg1 <- getArgs  
       txt  <- getContents 
       putStr((snd (unzip (zip (txt) (cycle(head arg1))))))
```

The **xor** function is located in *Data.Bits*.

I have tried using **xor** many times, but I am not sure how I would decrypt the text.

Please give some ideas.

So if the text was:

```
cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ
```

`"Hello World, Goodbye World"` it should replace the text with the KEY `(XXAYSAAZZ)` infinitely i.e.

`"XXAYSAAZZXXAYSAAZZXXAYSAAZ"` and  `cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ` should give back:

```
"Hello World, Goodbye World"
```

If you call it twice it returns the original string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the encryption scheme. Can you explain that further?

Comment: The Key should replace the text on output, so cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt 1235423 where the text in text file is "Hello World" should give "12354231235", and cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt 1235423 | ./encrypt 1235423 should give "Hello World"

Comment: @DesiBoyz If the key replaces the input, there's no way to get the input back. You can only get the input back if the encryption is a one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
putStr((snd (unzip (zip (txt) (cycle(head arg1))))))
```

just replaces the text with an equally long part of the cycled key. It is impossible to retrieve the text from that, since all information except its length has been lost.

It seems that the encryption is intended to `xor` each text character with the paired key character (cycling the key to get sufficient length).

For such a scheme, the `zipWith` function is intended,

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

here,

```
let cypher = zipWith xor text (cycle key)
```

But you should check that the key is nonempty, or it won't work. However, there's another problem you have to solve, there is no

```
instance Bits Char where
```

defined (and since so far `Bits` has a superclass constraint of `Num` - that is slated to be removed - there can't be). So you need to transform your key and plaintext to a type with a `Bits` instance, the easiest way is using the `Enum` instance of `Char`

```
main = do
  (key:_) <- getArgs
  if null key
     then error "encryption key must be nonempty"
     else do
       let xkey = map fromEnum (cycle key)
       plain <- getContents
       let cypher = map toEnum (zipWith xor xkey $ map fromEnum plain)
       putStr cypher
```

Comment: Running it once i.e. cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ to replace the text with an equally long part of the cycled key and then calling it twice i.e. cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ should return the original string.

Comment: It does, that's how xor works.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some problems beyond what you're asking about. For instance, you're never actually applying the XOR operation to your input.

Try changing your final line to this (I also took the liberty of eradicating your extreme infestation of parentheses):

```
putStr . map chr $ zipWith xor (map ord txt) (cycle . map ord $ head arg1)
```

The key here is `zipWith`, which zips two lists together using a combining function. `zip` can be thought of as a special case of `zipWith` (namely, `zipWith (,)`).

You also must convert the `String`s to `Bits a => [a]` in order to XOR their contents. This is done via `map ord`, which turns the `String` into a `[Int]` (`Int` has an instance of `Bits`). Then once the XORing is done, you convert the resulting `[Int]` back to a `String` with `map chr`.

As far as decryption is concerned, you should be able to just pass the encrypted text back through the same program (using the same key, of course) to recover the original plaintext. XOR is cool like that.

Comment: Running it once i.e. cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ to replace the text with an equally long part of the cycled key and then calling it twice i.e. cat txtfile.txt | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ | ./encrypt XXAYSAAZZ should return the original string.

Comment: @DesiBoyz Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @DesiBoyz are you saying that this program doesn't return the original string when piped through a second instance?

Comment: I think I like this version slightly better than Daniel's because I prefer `ord` and `chr` to `fromEnum` and `toEnum` when `Char` is involved.  Also, in this version, the key is transformed, and then cycled, instead of having to cycle the transform (although who knows if GHC can transform one into the other...).  Having said that, I prefer to name the key instead of referring to `head arg1`.

Answer (score 2):

What **I**'ve understood from your comment is that you want an one time pad encryption algorithm. Here's the Vernam implementation

```
Prelude> let vernam p t = zipWith (\a b -> Data.Char.chr $ Data.Bits.xor (Data.Char.ord a) (Data.Char.ord b)) (cycle p) t
Prelude> vernam "XXAYSAAZZ" "The World is Not Enough"
"\f0$y\EOT.36>x12y\GS.5z\US674>;"
Prelude> vernam "XXAYSAAZZ" "\f0$y\EOT.36>x12y\GS.5z\US674>;"
"The World is Not Enough"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I understand this correctly, you're trying to do xor encryption here? Just FYI, I believe XOR only works on binary strings. I don't think there's some automatic duck typing that would make your plaintext respond as binary. You have to convert your string to binary first, then you can xor it with the key to encrypt it. To decrypt, just xor the key with the message text.

Look at the type signature for the function here.

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Bits.html

You can't just feed it plaintext.