# scrambling txt file using compiler

Tags: haskell

I am new at Haskell and I'm having problems trying to get this script to work. This script reads in arguments from a command line and find them in a separate text file.

```
cat.txt | ./scramble A123456A123456 (in compiler)
```

The output should be like that:

```
The cat was very sad   ...etc.
++++++++++++++++++++
A123456A123456A123456 ...etc.
```

So it replaces whatever is in the text file with "A123456" infinitely.

```
module Main where
import System
import Data.Char (chr, ord, isLower)
import Data.Bits

let2int                       :: Char -> Int
let2int c                     =  ord c - ord 'a'

int2let                       :: Int -> Char
int2let n                     =  chr (ord 'a' + n)

shift                         :: Int -> Char -> Char
    shift n c | isLower c     =  int2let ((let2int c + n) `mod` 26)
              | otherwise     =  c

main = do 
arg1 <- getArgs
txt <- getContents
putStr (scramble txt arg1)


scramble :: Int -> String -> String  
scramble shift msg = 
let ords = map ord msg  
    shifted = map (+ shift) ords  
 in  map chr shifted
```

However, when I try to compile this, GHCi returns the error:

```
redact.hs:19:26:
Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type '[Char]'
Expected type: Int
 Actual type: [String]
In the second argument of 'scramble', namely 'txt'
In the first of 'putStr', namely '<redact txt arg1>' 
Failed, module loaded: none.
```

So the code:

```
putStr (scramble txt arg1)
```

is causing the problem.
I have also tried:

```
arg1:_ <- getArgs
```

but it doesn't help

Thank you in advance for any help and if you can improve the code in anyway that would be great.

Comment: @user1284290 Copy+paste your source code and the error message into your question instead of retyping them wrongly.

Comment: What do you mean by "using compiler"?  Also, is this homework?

Comment: Appears to be an assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866421/text-scrambler-in-haskell-using-key-from-ghci

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931300/haskell-encryption-program

Comment: Please give more specific information about what are you expecting of your program for some specific first argument and specific input text example.

Answer (score 2):

Three things that I can see:

1. You have the arguments that you pass to `scramble` in `main` the wrong way round.
2. You haven't defined `getContents` anywhere.
3. You're not using `getArgs` as you require.

As you guessed, you only need to get the first argument (as `getArgs :: IO [String]`); using `arg1:_ <- getArgs` will indeed get you the first argument (assuming there is at least one, otherwise there will be an error).  However, you will have that `arg1 :: String`, and you require an `Int`, so you need a function of type [`String -> Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aread).

This is my understanding based upon how you've defined `scramble` (which seems to be something like a Vigenere cipher), which is completely different from how you defined your initial problem.

Comment: [`getContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:getContents) is in the Prelude.

Comment: @dave4420: whoops, my mistake; I was thinking of reading something in from file rather than stdin :s

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked for me

```
(keys:_) <- getArgs
```

---

and is that the full code for the scramble